# 7z bzip2 format command line error

Tags: command-line, compression, 7zip, bzip2

I am trying to compress a couple of text files to bzip2 format using command line. Here is the format of command I am running:

**7z a -tbzip2 -r "C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\TestS\test.bzip2" *.txt  "C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\TestS"**

There are no sub folders inside this folder. The error I am getting is :
System Error:
The Parameter is incorrect.

When I am running the similar command for another format, its running fine.
7z a -tzip -r "C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\TestS\test.bzip2" *.txt  "C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\TestS"

Can someone please help me here with finding a correct command line syntax for bzip2?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The bzip2 format only supports compression and not archiving, therefore it only supports one file per archive.
To add multiple bzip2 compressed files into one archive the bzip2 format must be used in conjunction with an archive format, for instance a [tar archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)).

For 7-Zip, see the authors comment on the [7-Zip discussion page](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/733ae79e/) on SourceForge.